# Find pair with maximum Appeal value

Tags: arrays

**Find pair with maximum Appeal value.**

- Input: Array
- Output: index {i, j} ( i = j allowed) with maximum Appeal
- Appeal = A[i] +A[j] + abs(i-j)

**Example 1:**

- Input: [1, 3, -1]
- Output: [1, 1]
- Explanation: Appeal = A[1] + A[1] + abs(0) = 3 + 3 + 0 = 6

**Example 2:**

- Input: [1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7]
- Output: [1, 6]
- Explanation 6 + 7 + abs(1 - 6) = 18

**Example 3:**

- Input: [6, 2, 7, 4, 4, 1, 6]
- Output: [0, 6]
- Explanation: 6 + 6 + abs(0 - 6) = 18

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I've tried the 2 pointer approach as below and it seems to work for some cases but I'm missing some fundamental intuition about it.

```
public static int[] maximumAppeal(int[] A) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = A.length - 1;
    int max = 0;
    int[] r = {-1,-1};
    while (left <= right) {
        int sum = A[left] + A[right] + Math.abs(left - right);
        if (A[left] <= A[right]) {
            if (sum > max) {
                max =sum;
                r[0] = left;
                r[1] = right;
            }
            left++;
        } else {
            if (sum > max) {
                max = sum;
                r[0] = left;
                r[1] = right;
            }
            right--;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Edited:
Here's the link, its an Amazon question
https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/355698

Comment: This looks like a competition question -- please post a link to it, so that we can see if it's still live. Some of us prefer to help only when we can see that the question is not part of a live competition.

Comment: Has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B[i] = A[i] + i$ and let $C[j] = A[j] - j$. You are looking for
$$
\max_{i \geq j} B[i] + C[j] = \max_j (C[j] + \max_{i \geq j} B[i]).
$$

This gives a linear time in-place algorithm for your problem:

- maxB = A[n] + n
- maxSum = A[n] - n + maxB
- for j=n-1 downto 1:

  1. maxB = max(maxB, A[j] + j)
  2. candidate = A[j] - j + maxB
  3. maxSum = max(candidate, maxSum)
- return maxSum